# Difference between curvature and Ricci scalar curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, differentiation

I know about curvature by this notation 
$$\tau=\frac{dt}{ds}$$
the change of tangent vector with respect to arc length $s$ .

I also know about  Ricci scalar curvature is 
$$g^{ij}R_{ij}=R$$

I know the formulas. But i want to really know about their differences and some helpful geometrical interpretations.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2447/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92741/2451 and links therein.

Comment: i thought i will get better explanations and geometrical interpretations from physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula $\tau = \frac{dt}{ds}$ requires a correction, namely $t$ is not just any old tangent vector but is instead the *unit length* tangent vector. Also, that notion of curvature, which is known as "geodesic curvature", applies only to curves (1-dimensional objects) in space, the one parameter being $s$.

On the other hand Ricci curvature applies only to 2-or-higher dimensional objects in space.

So, you're not going to find much in the way of a direct comparison between those two types of curvature.

Still, though, there are some indirect comparisons in some limited situations. One particularly close connection occurs for a 2-dimensional surface $S$ in 3-dimensional space. The Ricci curvature at a point $P \in S$ is equal to the Gaussian curvature (because in 2 dimensions there's nothing to contract in the contraction formula that you give). And the Gaussian curvature is equal to the product of two different geodesic curvatures, namely the so-called "principle curvatures" which are the maximum and minimum values of $\tau$ for curves passing through $P$.

Comment: Can we modify the Gaussian  curvature to become the Ricci scalar curvature ?

Comment: As I said, in dimension 2 they are the same. In higher dimensions, there is still a relation between Gaussian curvature and Ricci curvature, the intermediary between the two being the Riemann curvature tensor.