# Physical meaning of the Riemann curvature tensor with all 4 lower indexes

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Since Riemann with 1 upper and 3 lower index mean the changes of a vector after being parallel transported around a closed loop, does Riemann with all 4 lower indexes mean the changes of a co-vector after being parallel transported around a closed loop? If not, what does it actually mean?

Note that, [What is the physical meaning of the connection and the curvature tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-connection-and-the-curvature-tensor) does not answer my question. I know what $R^a_{bcd}$ means, I also understand the meaning of the Ricci Tensor. What I'm curious about is the meaning of Riemann in all indeces lowered, i.e, $R_{abcd}$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2447/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/765973/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the physical meaning of the connection and the curvature tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2447/)

Comment: It doesn’t ans my question.